# Android APK with google maps is not installing in device

Tags: android, google-maps, intellij-idea, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I have created android application with google maps API and working fine when I run from IntelliJ IDE (running in connected device). But when I try to install APK file on device I am getting "Unfortunately, Package installer has stopped" error.

Note: I've generated APK with default debug self signed certificate and this application used install before adding google maps.

Any one faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your device is having the same app with different fingerprints. So it is not installing. Remove the old app and install new one.

Comment: I've removed old app and restarted device but no luck.